# laravel eloquent extracting the array from the object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my controller I am returning a query and want to convert the results into an array I can use.  In my unit test I want to make sure the return array is a count of three.

I keep getting this

```
+baseResponse: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse^ {#3966
    #data: "[{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"8","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"},{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"5","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"},{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"0","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"}]"
    #callback: null
    #encodingOptions: 0
    +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag^ {#3996
      #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
        "no-cache" => true
        "private" => true
      ]
      #cookies: []
      #headerNames: array:3 [
        "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
        "date" => "Date"
        "content-type" => "Content-Type"
      ]
      #headers: array:3 [
        "cache-control" => array:1 [
          0 => "no-cache, private"
        ]
        "date" => array:1 [
          0 => "Tue, 04 Aug 2020 18:57:56 GMT"
        ]
        "content-type" => array:1 [
          0 => "application/json"
        ]
      ]
      #cacheControl: []
    }
    #content: "[{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"8","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"},{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"5","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"},{"id":0,"title":"Alphabet","content":"A, B, C","views":"0","timestamp":"1596567476","created_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56","updated_at":"2020-08-04 18:57:56"}]"
    #version: "1.1"
    #statusCode: 200
    #statusText: "OK"
    #charset: null
    +original: array:3 [
      0 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "8"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
      1 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "5"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
      2 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "0"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
    ]
    +exception: null
  }
  #streamedContent: null
```

I only want this

```
  0 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "8"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
      1 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "5"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
      2 => array:7 [
        "id" => 0
        "title" => "Alphabet"
        "content" => "A, B, C"
        "views" => "0"
        "timestamp" => "1596567476"
        "created_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
        "updated_at" => "2020-08-04 18:57:56"
      ]
```

Here is the code for my controller.

```
 public function retrieveStore(Request $request)
    {
        $params = $request->query("query");
        $params = $this->refineParams("/LESS_THAN\s*\(.+\)/m", "<", $params);
        $params = $this->refineParams("/GREATER_THAN\s*\(.+\)/m", ">", $params);
        $params = $this->refineParams("/EQUAL\s*\(.+\)/m", "=", $params);
     
        $json = Post::whereRaw($params)->get();
        return response()->json($json->toArray(), 200);
    }

    private function refineParams($regex, $symbol, $params)
    {
        $fields = ["id" => 0, "title" => 0, "content" => 0, "views" => 0, "timestamp" => 0];
        preg_match_all($regex, $params,
        $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        foreach($out as $key){
            $str = implode($key);
            $begining = strpos($str, '(') + 1;
            $end = strpos($str, ',') -  $begining;
            $firstValue = substr($str,  $begining , $end);
            $firstValue  = str_replace(' ', '', $firstValue);
            $begining = strpos($str, ',') + 1;
            $end = strpos($str, ')') -  $begining;
            $endValue = substr($str,  $begining , $end);
            $endValue = str_replace(' ', '', $endValue);
            if(array_search($firstValue, $fields) > -1 && ($endValue === "0" || (int)$endValue > 0)){
                $params = str_replace($str, $firstValue . $symbol . $endValue, $params);
            }
        }
        return $params;
    }
```

What am I missing to turn my results into an array I can use?

Comment: no need to call `toArray()` when using json response, it will call `toArray()->toJson()` automatically. `return response()->json($json, 200);`

Comment: what are you doing that you are getting that actual response object dumped like that?

Comment: @lagbox I am writing a unit test and trying to get that the array is count of three.

Comment: @N69S I originally started with return response()->json($json, 200);, but go much more data back.  How would I convert this into an array I can use in a unit test

Comment: this is what responses look like before the framework actually sends them out ... if you are going to be directly calling things like this then you are going to get what you returned which is a Response object ... you can very easily get the data/content of that object though

Comment: as @lagbox said, in your unit test, call for the method `content()` from the jsonResponse objecy you intercepted. `$response->content()` or in your controller, do `return $json->toJson();`

Comment: @N69S thanks, I spent way to longe trying to figure that out

Comment: you may want  `getOriginalContent()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are calling your Controller method directly, unit testing it, you will get back what you returned which in this case is a `JsonResponse` object. You can get the content of that object though.

If you want what the content will be like after the response is sent you can get it via `$response->content()` or `$response->getContent()`.  If the content should be JSON it will convert it and set the `$content` of the response to that JSON.

If you want the actual original data that is the content for this Response you can get that specifically:

```
$response->getOriginalContent();
```

That should give you your original array.